# Ui-router: inject service from resolved module in next resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that needs to load an entire module asynchronously. The following code does that for me, and it works great (for the sake of clarity, I removed anything not needed, including annotations for automated injections):

```
$stateProvider.state('root.lazy', {
  url: '/lazy',
  resolve: {
    loadModule: function($ocLazyLoad) {
      return getModuleAsync().then(function(module) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name: module.name
        });
      });
    }
});
```

Now, this module also register a service - say `lazyService` which gets data asynchronously. I'd like to resolve these data once the module is loaded. So I tried:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.lazy', {
  url: '/lazy',
  resolve: {
    loadModule: function($ocLazyLoad) {
      return getModuleAsync().then(function(module) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name: module.name
        });
      });
    },
    data: function(loadModule, lazyService) {  // So ui-router knows it needs the previous resolve; but it fails trying to inject lazyService
      return lazyService.getData();
    }
});
```

But ui-router gives me the following error: `Unknown provider: lazyServiceProvider <- lazyService`.

Using some debugging logs, I found out that ui-router may try to inject everything needed in the resolve functions before actually resolving anything. Indeed, the error pops *before* any logs I put in the `loadModule` function. But `loadModule` resolves eventually, and then everything is available but the data.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want without using a super state resolving the module and a nested state resolving the data? Given the current app context, it makes sens for us to resolve both things in the same state.

**EDIT:** I'm using ui-router 1.0.4 with AngularJS 1.5

Comment: Can you update to version 1.0? It has future states support and this use case works out of the box.

Comment: @ChrisT Strange, I'm already using version 1.0 (should have mentioned that, sorry; question edited), but haven't seen it in the doc before your comment. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisT Moving my `loadModule` function to the field `lazyLoad` in my state declaration worked (getting my `$ocLazyLoad` with the first param of the function instead of injecting it: `lazyLoad: (transitions, state) => transition.injector().get('$ocLazyLoad'). ...`). Feel free to write a short answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!